# Is there a way to export a value conditionally on a selection?

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements, dropdown, categories

I have some very basic Typescript code:

```
export const defaultListingFormValues = {
  itemWeight: 1
}
```

Is there a way to change the default value of `itemWeight` to be conditional based on an item's category selected via a dropdown for a listing form?

Something like `dress = 0.5, heels = 1, boots = 2, etc.` depending on which option is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your `defaultListingFormValues` with category `objects` as `{ itemWeight: 1, dress: { itemWeight: 1 },... }`.

And use it with `category` value from dropdown as below. Here categoryFromDropDown holds `category from dropdown` i.e. `dress`. Used `condition` so if any `category` is not defined then it will return `default` value.

```
let defaultValue = defaultListingFormValues[categoryFromDropDown] ?
      defaultListingFormValues[categoryFromDropDown].itemWeight :
      defaultListingFormValues.itemWeight;
```

Try it below. For demo `export` & `import` statements are commented.

```js
// export const defaultListingFormValues = {
const defaultListingFormValues = {
  itemWeight: 1,
  dress: {
    itemWeight: 0.5
  },
  heels: {
    itemWeight: 1
  },
  boots: {
    itemWeight: 2
  }
}

// When you access 
// import defaultListingFormValues from '...';
let categoryFromDropDown = 'dress';
let defaultValue = defaultListingFormValues[categoryFromDropDown] ?
  defaultListingFormValues[categoryFromDropDown].itemWeight :
  defaultListingFormValues.itemWeight;
  
console.log(defaultValue);

// category which is not present in defaultListingFormValues.
categoryFromDropDown = 'aaa';
defaultValue = defaultListingFormValues[categoryFromDropDown] ?
  defaultListingFormValues[categoryFromDropDown].itemWeight :
  defaultListingFormValues.itemWeight;
  
console.log(defaultValue);
```